# Using a regression beta coefficient as a KPI?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, inference, business-intelligence

I have a complicated mixed effects regression that predicts the log_price. One of the regression parameters estimates the Beta_1, difference in log price between group A and group B.

Group A is expected to stay relatively stationary while group B is expected to be:

- lower than group A
- and either be:

  - stationary
  - or decrease relative to group A over time

If I wanted to turn this into a KPI, can I just refit the model once per week and log the beta coefficient estimate (mean and standard deviation)? Or does that not make sense since there's uncertainty in that estimate?

Comment: I would be more hesitant to use something like that as a KPI for a bigger reason: KPIs are very often metrics that non-technical people track. The "beta coefficient estimate" is not likely to be very meaningful for non-technical people.

Comment: Well if you exponentiate the beta coefficient in that case, it becomes "percent of money group B is saving relative to group A" which is a more simple context for them to understand. Does that help get around that argument? I definitely see your point of course. The bigger thing I'm concerned at is measuring a parameter and not a real concrete number over time, I have no clue if that part makes sense

Comment: Much better! If you have a concrete interpretation of any particular number, that makes it a much better candidate for a KPI. I wouldn't say that "uncertainty in that estimate" is an argument against using a particular number as a KPI. That would be true for any statistic! Naturally, if you can conduct a census and get the parameter's value, that's better - but that's often impractical.